# Spring SpEL not working for <mvc:resources> location parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resources, spring-el

This works:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="file:///C:/Temp/" />
```

This does not work:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="#{systemEnvironment['MY_SYS_VAR']}"/>
```

where MY_SYS_VAR is an environment variable set to "C:/Temp/"

Note: Any variation such as

```
location="file:///#{systemEnvironment['MY_SYS_VAR']}"
```

or

```
location="#{'file:///' + systemEnvironment['MY_SYS_VAR']}"
```

doesn't seem to work either.

I think that this is related to https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9291; however, the defect is marked as resolved (fixed), and I am using Spring 3.2

Comment: What is `systemEnvironment`? Did you mean `systemProperties`?

Comment: `systemProperties` are system properties i.e. parameters specified with -D to the java command. `systemEnvironment` is the environment (i.e windows or linux environment variables). See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/StandardEnvironment.html?is-external=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched from 3.2.2 to 3.2.8 and it is now working with the spring expression.